# Accessing the package with the same name as a class in a *.jar

Tags: java, deobfuscation

I have a *.jar file and i want to use some classes from it. Among the others, it contains class "a" from package "com.a.a" and package "com.a.a.a.a.e" with class "a". When i try to access the class as "com.a.a.a.a.e.a", there is an error: com.a.a.a.a cannot be resolved to a type. It happens because compiler tries to get the field "a" of class "com.a.a.a" rather than package "com.a.a.a.a". I also tried to import this class, but it makes no difference, and i get the error "The import com.a.a.a.a cannot be resolved".

Is there any way to use the class "com.a.a.a.a.e.a"? Are there any tools that are able to rename classes in *.jar? Or may be reflection can help here?

Comment: `...When i try to access the class...` can you provide this code?

Comment: I just try to call the constructor. `b localObject2 = (b)Guice.createInjector(new Module[] { new com.a.a.a.a.e.a() }).getInstance(b.class);`

Comment: If you want to change the behaviour of obfuscated classes, you can try some runtime instrumentation trick, AspectJ for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JAR you're trying to use has most likely been [obfuscated](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/how-obfuscation-helps-protect-java-from-reverse-engineering/444), probably for the purpose of preventing what you're trying to do. Some Java obfuscators change the package, class, method, and variable names to violate the JLS but still be valid compiled bytecode; that appears to be exactly what has been done to this JAR. It will be very difficult to make sense of the de-compiled code in that case.

JARs that are obfuscated usually leave just their public API un-obfuscated for your code to use; everything else is scrambled to prevent you from de-compiling it and/or using it directly.

Comment: I don't think they actually violate the JLS, as naming conventions are  after all, only conventions.

Comment: I've seen some obfuscators actually change identifiers to invalid names, such as ??? that user502144 wrote in a comment below. It makes decompiling the code nearly useless.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the JLS:

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be
>   interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these
>   situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen
>   in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference
>   to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a
>   visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that
>   such a declaration is obscured.

Reflection could help working around the problem. Although renaming classes can be a solution too in most situations, well-behaved jars shouldn't even have this problem. I suspect that your jar has been put through an obfuscation process, which, depending on how it was done, can make renaming classes complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Code Conventions - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html - and you will NEVER have such errors.

If you want to access jar - decompile it, fix it and assemble it back.

Comment: The aim is to decompile the *.jar, but when i compile it back, it generates over 900 errors. So, i began with modifying of the single package and fixing all errors in it. And i want to use functionality of all other packages via binary file.

Comment: There is a cool tool, called jd-gui. It is a free software - just unpack the jar to a project, fix and go on. I wouldn't advice you to create a .jar out of the OS...

Comment: Cool :D Well, I don't think that you could make a surgery on a file in a jar... Try to compile back. What kind of errors do you receive?

Comment: There are a lot of weird errors, such as: ??? instead of variables, undeclared or missing variables, and tons of unresolved classes and method names.

Comment: Have you tried to create a separate project, 4 example in eclipse, and assemble .jar using maven?

Comment: Have a try and if it is going to swear with some errors, at least you will know WHAT is happening. Just install any maven plugin to eclipse, and convert the project (first you decompile the sources from jar) to maven project. The reason you get some errors from the OS assembly is that the jar could have some references to some other jars...

Comment: The trouble is that obfuscated code relies on obscuring to prevent recompilation.